# Show UIViewController with Navigation Controller from a Modal opened one

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

i want to open a view controller thats appear from the right, with the proper navigation controller from a view controller opened modally.

Like in the image, view controller 1 is opened modally, now i want to open view controller 2 from the right side with the navigation controller...

Is it possible??

[image]

EDIT: the image with respective segues

[image]

Comment: OF course it is possible. The way you have in the storyboard is correct. What is the issue ? Did you try it ?

Comment: Yes i tried, the second view controller is presented modally too, no matter what kind of presentation i set

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  #1 is presented modally.  Do you want to present the navigation controller (with #2 as it's root) modally on top of #1?

Comment: that is exactly what i want to do

Comment: Remember that you are presenting the navigation controller modally. You can't change this unless 1 is embedded in navigaiton controller. Are you looking into custom push animation without a navigation controller.So that 2 appears like push animation though u r presenitng it modally ?

Comment: Look, i edit the question with another image

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty simple.

When "1" is presented modally, it is not a part of a navigation stack, or does not have a navigationController attached to it.

So hence you cannot "Push" from "1".

The solution is -->
Embed "1" into a navigationController.

Whoever is opening "1" modally, make it open the navigationController open modally.

And then if you want, hide the navBar using

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

And just in case, you are passing parameters to "1" from the caller, use

```
  UINavigationController * navigationController =  segue.destinationviewController;
    //OR
    UINavigationController * navigationController =  [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NavController"];

    OneViewController *controller =    [navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: what do you mean exactly with "embed into a navigationController"? add a navigationController before the 1 view controller and make the 1 as the rootViewcontroller? i ask because i did it already and it does not work, the 2 view controller is still opened modally

Comment: You may have missed something. You open the NavigationController as Modal, and not "1"